# Prove summation formula for binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [simple binomial theorem proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254865/simple-binomial-theorem-proof)

Prove that:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{k+a}{k}=\frac{(n+a+1)!}{n! (a+1)!},
\end{equation}

where $a$ is a constant, without using induction. A probabilistic proof would be nice.

Comment: You’ll find both a combinatorial argument and a proof by induction at the earlier question cited above.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: And that was just yesterday!  I'm not sure how I missed that.

Comment: @Mike: Well, I *did* have a slight advantage! (Good to see you back, by the way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably $n$ and $a$ are nonnegative integers.
The right side is ${n+a+1} \choose n$.  Consider $n+a+1$ items, of which you want to choose $n$.  At least one of the first $n+1$ must be left out.  If the first item to be left out is number $n+1-k$ (where $0 \le k \le n$), then you already have chosen the first $n-k$ items, you are skipping number $n+1-k$ and you need to choose $k$ out of the remaining $n+a+1-(n+1-k) = a+k$.  The number of ways to do that is ${a+k} \choose k$.

Answer (score 0):

A similar result can be found [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rising_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients#Direct_Proof). The [corollary](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rising_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients#Corollary) is the result you seek. The [proof](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rising_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients#Proof_of_Corollary) of the corollary is on the same page. Hope this helps.