# Transition Probability

Tags: probability

I have a sequence like this:

> 6666666666677777777777777777666666644444444444444447777777

I would like to calculate the probability of transitions between numbers.

I tried with counting pairs (67, 76, 64...) and dividing them with the number off all pairs. I'm wondering is this approach valid? Any ides on some other approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not similar to the:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test

You might check if it's the same or similar problem.

Comment: Thank you, I found it already :)

Comment: same problem of yours ?