# Summation of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Is there a closed formula for:

$\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\binom{i+k}{i}}$

( k is a constant whole number )

Comment: See [$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451)

Answer (score 5):

Yes:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N\binom{i+k}i=\sum_{i=1}^N\binom{i+k}k=\sum_{i=0}^N\binom{i+k}k-1=\binom{N+k+1}{k+1}-1\;.$$

Comment: That also is ${N + k + 1 \choose N} - 1$ (well that's basically just b.c. symetry, but I find this one more elegant :3)

Comment: @servabat: It is indeed.

Comment: Can you please tell me how we get $\sum_{i=0}^N\binom{i+k}k-1=\binom{N+k+1}{k+1}-1$ ?

Comment: @Rayu: Ignoring the $-1$ on both sides, it’s a very standard identity involving binomial coefficients. See [this question and answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254865/simple-binomial-theorem-proof) for a couple of proofs.

Comment: @Rayu: You’re welcome.