# How to calculate $\sum_{m=1}^{N}\binom{m+k-1}{m}$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

What would be a simplified formula for $\displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{N}\binom{m+k-1}{m}$ for a given number $k$ and any number $N$?

Comment: This is quite an interesting problem but you should show what you've done so far or else your post is prone to getting downvotes.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Exactly what do you expect a person who doesn't know how to solve this problem to show?

Comment: If the problem was encountered in a class, what topics are you currently studying? If the problem was encountered in a book being read independently, in what section was the problem encountered? Have you tried anything? If so, what, and where did you get stuck? Context such as this helps someone give an appropriate answer.

Comment: This summation actually occurs in [this recent answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1218512/18880). Any relation to that question.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{N}{m+k-1\choose m}
&=\sum_{m=1}^{N}{m+k-1\choose k-1}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{N}\left[{m+k\choose k}-{m+k-1\choose k}\right]\\
&=\sum_{m=2}^{N+1}{m+k-1\choose k}-\sum_{m=1}^N{m+k-1\choose k}\\
&={N+k\choose k}-{k\choose k}\\
&={N+k\choose k}-1\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: This should in fact have been closed as a duplicate, e.g., of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219014/summation-of-binomial-coefficients/1219022#1219022).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following formula:
$$\displaystyle\binom{m+k-1}{m}=\binom{m+k}{m}-\binom{m+k-1}{m-1}$$

Proof:

\begin{align}
\binom{m+k}{m}-\binom{m+k-1}{m-1}&=\dfrac{(m+k)!}{m!\:k!}-\dfrac{(m+k-1)!}{(m-1)!\:k!}
\\
&=\dfrac{(m+k-1)!}{(m-1)!\:k!}\left(\dfrac{m+k}{m}-1\right)
\\
&=\dfrac{(m+k-1)!}{m!\:(k-1)!}
\\
&=\binom{m+k-1}{m}
\end{align}

So
\begin{align}
\sum \limits_{m=1}^{N}\binom{m+k-1}{m}&=\sum \limits_{m=1}^{N}(\binom{m+k}{m}-\binom{m+k-1}{m-1})
\\
&=\sum \limits_{m=1}^{N}\binom{m+k}{m}-\sum \limits_{m=1}^{N}\binom{m+k-1}{m-1}
\\
&=\sum \limits_{m=1}^{N}\binom{m+k}{m}-\sum \limits_{m=0}^{N-1}\binom{m+k}{m}
\\
&=\sum \limits_{m=1}^{N}\binom{m+k}{m}-\sum \limits_{m=1}^{N-1}\binom{m+k}{m}-1
\\
&=\binom{N+k}{N}-1
\end{align}

Comment: Got it..Thanks.:)

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Try using a [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) and the recursion for [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_triangle)
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^N\binom{m+k-1}{m}
&=\sum_{m=1}^N\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^N\left[\binom{m+k}{k}-\binom{m+k-1}{k}\right]\\
&=\binom{N+k}{k}-\binom{k}{k}
\end{align}
$$